# How to set permission for a folder without cpanel access

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, file-permissions

Hello iam using wordpress and i need to set permission for a plugin folder to be 755, Iam the admin of the blog but i don't have permission in the cpanel is their a way to do it using php or any other stuff? badly need some help....

Comment: If you can FTP to your hosting, then you can set permission with it. Most FTP client's support setting file permission.

Comment: with php chmod http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php, but is easier with ftp\ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP you say?

```
chmod("/foo/bar", 0755);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php